# How to sync code between container and host using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Until now, I have used a local LAMP stack to develop my web projects and deploy them manually to the server. For the next project I want to use docker and docker-compose to create a mariaDB, NGINX and a project container for easy developing and deploying.

When developing I want my code directory on the host machine to be synchronised with the docker container. I know that could be achieved by running

```
docker run -dt --name containerName -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container
```

in the cli as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650951/sharing-files-between-container-and-host), but I want to do that within a docker-compose v2 file.

I am as far as having a docker-composer.yml file looking like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
    db:
        #[...]
    myProj:
        build: ./myProj
        image: myProj
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            myCodeVolume:/var/www
volumes:
    myCodeVolume:
```

How can I synchronise my /var/www directory in the container with my host machine (Ubuntu desktop, macos or Windows machine)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just checking; You wrote `docker-composer.yml` instead of `docker-compose.yml`. Not sure if that was a typo or not (other thing might not have worked if you had really run the former), but thought I'd check.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is pretty much the same way, you do the `host:container` mapping directly under the `services.myProj.volumes` key in your compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    ...
    myProj:
        ...
        volumes:
            /path/to/file/on/host:/var/www
```

**Note** that the top-level `volumes` key is removed.

This file could be translated into:

```
docker create --links db -v /path/to/file/on/host:/var/www myProj
```

When `docker-compose` finds the top-level `volumes` section it tries to `docker volume create` the keys under it first before creating any other container. Those volumes could be then used to hold the data you want to be persistent across containers.
So, if I take your file for an example, it would translate into something like this:

```
docker volume create myCodeVolume
docker create --links db -v myCodeVoume:/var/www myProj
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand you right, I can use the top-level volumes for sharing files between containers and the inside-services volumes for container-host sharing?

Comment: Yes. But to complete the answer, inside-services volumes can still be used the same way as it would via the CLI :)

Comment: Just 2 remarks about the provided pseudo-yaml: `services.myProj.volumes` must be a list, so add a `-` in front of the path. Also, if you don't wont to provide the full path on the host system, start the path with a `.`-char. The final line would look like this: `- ./path/to/file/on/host:/var/www`